# imagecopy - cropping image instead of resizing

Tags: php, html, gd

I want to resize - `$artfile`, and put store to `$dest` starting from `$start_x, $start_y`.

`$dest` contains a frame. `$artfile` needs to fit within the frame so I need to resize it.

my code is :

```
imagecopy($dest, $art_file, $start_x, $start_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height); // works fine but to test resize

$dest = my destination resource
$artfile = resource that I want to patch with $destination
$new_width, $new_height = I want $art_file to be resized to this value, without trimming off or cropping.
```

My problem is :

For any images that has more than the `$new_height` or `$new_width` dimension, the more is trimmed off. I want to resize the entire set to `$new_height` or `$new_width`.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

play with this, hope it can help you out some;

```
 <?php
 Function createthumbnail($src=null,$newHeight=null) {
    $srcimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $srcsize = getimagesize($src);
    $dest_y = $newHeight;
    $dest_x = ($newHeight / $srcsize[1]) * $srcsize[0];
    $thumbimg = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_x, $dest_y);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbimg,$srcimg,0,0,0,0,$dest_x,$dest_y, $srcsize[0], $srcsize[1]);
    $thumbimg = imagejpeg($thumbimg,$src);
    return $thumbimg;
}
?>
```

you can call it like this

```
<?php
resizedImage = createthumbnail(urlOfFileToResize,newHeight);//newHeight would be like 1 or 50 or 1000......
?>
```

now your resized image will be stored in resizedImage

you are welcome.